# How to bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost for Docker purposes

Tags: substrate

I am currently trying to wrap the entire Node in a Docker container. However substrate when i run it runs on localhost. I cannot seem to find a way to bind it to 0.0.0.0 since Docker doesn't play too nice binding to localhost due to the nature of VMs being intermediary for a lot of environments.

Comment: Hi Byrd, can you please support our Substrate StackExchange proposal: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out substrate has two flags needed to bind to that interface. --ws-external and --rpc-external. Both of those will allow that.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by the entire node?

You should be able to bind it like this: `--port 0.0.0.0:80:80` or use `--network host` (https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)

Comment: It's in regards to substrate. By default substrate binds to localhost instead of 0.0.0.0. So when I containerize it, it runs within the docker container at localhost so its not available on my host. I'm using Mac, so the host is vbox.

Answer (score 1):

Use `--ws-external` / `--rpc-external`, you may also need to specify `--rpc-cors all` if you want to access it from the web